# Is there a way to react to an Exception raising to the top of the program without try/except in Python?

Tags: python, exception

Can I catch and dump an exception (and the corresponding stacktrace) that would make the program crash without doing something like :

```
try:
   # whole program
except Execption as e:
   dump(e)
   raise
```

Sometime a external library crashes, and I'd like to react to Python dying and log the reasons it does so. I don't want to prevent the Exception from crashing the program, I just want the debug information.

Something like:

```
signals.register('dying', callback)

def callback(context):
    # dumping the exception and
    # stack trace from here
```

Is that even possible ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, by registering a [`sys.excepthook()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook):

```
import sys

def myexcepthook(type, value, tb):
    dump(type, value, tb)

sys.excepthook = myexcepthook
```

This *replaces* the default hook, which prints out the traceback to `stderr`. It is called whenever an uncaught exception is raised, and the interpreter is about to exit.

If you want to reuse the original exception hook from your custom hook, call `sys.__excepthook__`:

```
def myexcepthook(type, value, tb):
    dump(type, value, tb)
    sys.__excepthook__(type, value, tb)
```

Comment: I can successfully (from C++) call a function with PyObject_CallObject(), but if I intentionally send wrong number of parameters, it will return null. How can I use this hook to return the value back to the script?

Comment: @Qwerty: The C API gives you access to [Python exceptions](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/exceptions.html) directly.